# Reverse pseudo code

Tags: ida, hexrays

I am reversing a binary which seems to have all the symbols exported which helps.  What I have seen is a pile of variables and functions which all start with the letter '`v`', for example `v101`.  I have been playing around with the decompiler from IDA and noticed that its pseudo code generally uses the same form having variables starting with the letter '`v`'.  I know this may seem silly to ask but I am looking at a binary which is actually just IDA pro pseudo code compiled?

A snippet of pseudo code generated:

```
int v3480()
{
  __int32 v0; // r0@1

  v0 = time(0);
  srand48(v0);

  // TODO Object initialisation!!
  v877 = &v3688;
  v1277 = &v7299;
  v1634 = &v5690;
  v2042 = &v7024;

  v873 = &v3688;
  v872 = (char *)&v3688 + 1;
  v1274 = &v7299;
  v485 = &unk_40B69FF5;

  v1631 = &v5690;
  v1629 = (char *)&v5690 + 1;

  v2037 = &v7024;
  v2038 = (char *)&v7024 + 1;

  v5661 = -1;
  v2325 = -1;
  v1259 = -1;
  v4048 = -1;
  v5509 = &v5497;
  v3845 = &unk_40B69EEC;
  v3522 = &v4191;
  v7253 = &unk_40B69EE4;
  v2081 = &v3009;
  v5828 = &unk_40B69EDC;
  v7014 = &v2061;
  v3636 = &unk_40B69ED4;
  v217 = &v6520;
  v218 = &v6524;
  v219 = &v6525;
  v221 = &v6523;
  v1455 = &v6523;
  unk_40B69EF4 = &v6524;
  v7297 = &dword_40A071D0;
  v5530 = &dword_40A071D0;
  if ( dword_40A071D0 )
  {
    v6935();
  }
  else
  {
    memcpy(v219, &v5764, 0xE3958u);
    dword_40A071D0 = 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: that sounds more like obfuscation, if all variables are  like 'v'+NUMBER.

Comment: I suppose you should post part of the code so that the people who know what IDA's pseudo-code looks like can help. Otherwise, I don't think anybody can predict anything :D

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at pseudocode reconstructed from the binary.
After compilation all variable names disappeared, so IDA generates new generic ones.

It looks like that all v* variables are local (allocated on the stack)

Comment: Yes I know that but what I am seeing is that I have lots of functions in the original binary which have exported names starting with the character 'v' as well.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that these names exist before generating psuedo code

Comment: do you have debug information in this file ? i

Comment: Can you post the function pseudocode somewhere ?

Comment: Its above in the question

Comment: I wanted to see the whole fuinction

Comment: Sorry, I have posted the entire function as it appears in Hex-Rays.

Comment: OK, there are 3 possibilities here. Either you have debug information in the executable and it is obfuscated or there are problems with stack reconstruction in this specific function or it was somehow changed in IDA. What do you see when you double-clicking on v6935() ?

Comment: Double clicking v6935() takes me to the function which decompiles correctly

Comment: The binary was original packed with LZMA.  From what you are saying it looks that I have all the debug information and that it is obfuscated somehow.  The question is how do I determine what type of obfuscation I have?